# UIDatePicker setting minute to 1 when on the view 0 is selected

Tags: ios, datepicker

I'm using the same `UIDatePicker` instance to set three different values. Two of them are dates and the last is a time (e.g. 1:05).

My issue is regarding the use of the `UIDatePicker` when set in mode `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`. First the [doc says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) that when set in this mode, the `date` property is ignored and the `countDownDuration` must be used to fetch the value. In my case after setting the picker to this mode the `date` is not ignored <s>but the `countDownDuration` is (=null)!</s>
 **EDIT:** the property is correctly set, I simply not correctly logged it (`%@` modifier was used instead of `%f`); my next issue remains though.

The worst thing is that the date is correctly set but unfortunately not when I select 0:00. For this time, the date is set to 0:01!

Any help? What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. The picker shows 0 hours 0 minutes yet the value retrieved from countDownDuration is 1970-01-01 00:01:00 +0000.

Answer (score 1):

The count-down timer is intended for setting a time for count-down. So, zero simply makes no sense. Obviously the minimum value is constrained to 1 minute.

There is one strange behavior though: if you set the interval for the timer to more than 1 minute, you are able to select 0, but get 1 inside your code. When the interval is 1 minute, you notice that you cannot select 0 minutes in the picker; it snaps back. I consider the former behavior a bug. You should never be able to select 0 minutes, no matter how big the interval is.

Answer (score 0):

use UIDatePickerModeTime instead of count-down instead to select 00, but surely it will look some different from count-down, have a look:

```
_datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
_datePicker.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
```