# UIDatePicker unwanted behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I created UIDatePicker with style of Cut Down Timer then added Interval with 12 minutes. It's look like this:
[image]

Then I select **1 hour and 0 minutes** now want to see how much is selected (in the code):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *selected = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[CutdownDatePicker date]];
```

Now i print a value of **slected** and it;s shows **01:01:00** which is 1 hour and 1 minute, but i selected 0 minutes ?

Everything is fine if i select 12, 24, 48 minute but if i select 0 minutes it's add me 1 minute.

Please help with this unwanted behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875595/uidatepicker-setting-minute-to-1-when-on-the-view-0-is-selected.You cannot change this behavior as described in the link

Comment: Maybe there is workaround of this behavior and someome done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a count down date picker. Don't ask for its `date`; that is meaningless. Ask for its `countDownDuration`.

Comment: However it's still returns +1 minute

Comment: But since the user cannot select 1 minute (it is not on the date picker), your code knows instantly if the countDownDuration has 1 minute that the user must have selected 0 minute. So there is really no problem. You just subtract a minute and start timing. This is the nice thing about the count down date picker: it is not really a timer, it's just an interface for telling *you* where to count down from.